# Text not showing up in prepended select option added VIA jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an issue where I added an option to multiple select controls VIA jQuery. the option does show up corectly but has not text, furthermore, the option does not show up in the chrome inspector.

How do I set the text in the option?

```
$('.muffler-type-control').on('change', function(){
    $('.muffler-type-control').each(function(){
        if(!$(this).find('option[text="--- Please Select ---"]')){
            $(this).prepend('<option value="">--- Please Select ---</option>')
                   .text('--- Please Select ---');
        }
    });

    var selectedValue = $(this).val();

    $('.muffler-type-control').val('');
    $('.container-muffler-type-control').removeClass('required');

    $(this).val(selectedValue);
    $(this).parent().addClass('required');
    $(this).find("option").eq(0).remove();
});
```

the above always adds the option to each control correctly, but there is no text in the option - I need it to say "--- Please Select ---"

I have tried:

```
$(this).prepend('<option value="">--- Please Select ---</option>');    
$(this).prepend('<option value=""></option>').text('--- Please Select ---');    
$(this).prepend('<option value="">--- Please Select ---</option>').text('--- Please Select ---');
```

none give the desired result.

Comment: Try this.  Get the entire select html (which will be as a string) and then alter the string and use $(this).html(theString).

Answer (score 0):

I did not quite figure out why this did not work, but I think it had something to do with testing if the option object existed [on object exists whether or not the option is there or not] but this is how I worked around it:

```
$('.muffler-type-control').on('change', function(){

    $('.muffler-type-control').each(function(){

        var myOption = $(this).find('option').eq(0).text();

        if(myOption != ' --- Please Select --- '){
            console.log('adding select');
            $(this).prepend('<option value=""> --- Please Select --- </option>');
        }            

    });

    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    $('.muffler-type-control').val('');
    $('.container-muffler-type-control').removeClass('required');
    $(this).val(selectedValue);
    $(this).parent().addClass('required');
    $(this).find("option").eq(0).remove();


});
```

Answer (score -1):

Why is the prepend block inside an onchange block? It will only happen if a selectbox has changed....

Anyways, here is a small example, that works simply with prepend:

https://jsfiddle.net/zc1uLycc/

```
$('#test').prepend('<option value="">--- Please Select ---</option>');
```